# custom page taking long to load on wordpress It only show post for today (or latest post)

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

This custom Page is taking at least 40 seconds to load. The other pages are loading in under 3 seconds. I want to show the post only for today on the front page like a today's news. 
What's wrong with the code?

```
<div class="row">
 <?php list($latest_post) = get_posts( array( "posts_per_page"=>1 )); 
    $date = substr($latest_post->post_date, 0,10); // Show only news from this date
 ?> 

<div class="medium-8 large-8 columns" role="main">
<?php 
unset($counter);
/*these are the category ID */
$cats = array(49, 10, 50);
#$cats = get_categories(); 
foreach($cats AS $cat):
    $posts = get_posts( array( "posts_per_page"=>100, "category"=>$cat )); 
    $catname = get_the_category_by_ID($cat);

    $foundPost = false;
    foreach($posts AS $post):
        $postdate = substr($post->post_date, 0,10);
        if($postdate!=$date) break;

        if(!$foundPost) { // Print title if at least one post is found
            $foundPost = true;
        if ( in_category('Category Text') ) {   
            echo '<div class="redBackground">'.$catname.'</div>';
            }
        }   
        ?>

        <?php
        the_post(); 
        ?>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="small-2 columns"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></div>
  <div class="small-10 columns"> <div class="fontSize"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
  <div class="contentTag"><?php the_tags(''); ?></div>
<div class="contentText"> <span style="color: #000"><?php echo people_Content(150); ?></span>
            </div></div>
                </div>
            <?php

?>  
        <?php
    endforeach;
endforeach; ?>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see "posts_per_page"=>100 -- How many posts are showing because 100 could take a little while depending on what's being shown.

Comment: Thanks that helps a bit. But it's still kind of slower

Comment: You don't have to loop through all of those. I'm writing some code for an answer.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run a more selective query and only select the posts that are for the day you are on. Below is a query with a loop that should get you where you need to go:

```
//Get todays date
$today = getdate();
/*these are the category ID */
$cats = array(49, 10, 50);
//setup arguments for query including today's date
$args = array(
  'category__in' => $cats,
  'date_query' => array(
      'year'  => $today['year'],
      'month' => $today['mon'],
      'day'   => $today['mday'],
  )
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // this is where you will print out the details of each post
    }
} else {
    //There were no posts for today.
}

// Restore original Post Data (you may not need this but it can't hurt)
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I found a bug so I updated the code. You can put any of your output code where the comment says "this is where you will print out the details of each post". The gist of the answer is that you need to run the query as shown. I added the loop in so you can place your code in the correct spot. The code would go in your div with the role="main".

Comment: Also what if I want to still have the latest post on my front page that is not today news? I dont want to put There were no post for today, I want to have the lastest post instead. Thanks

Comment: @ParbhuBissessar You would check if the query above had any results and if it didn't run the normal query.